# Gettext msgid is empty

Tags: c, locale, gettext

The `xgettext` command extracted this `.pot` from my .c file:

```
#: src/callbacks.c:171
msgid ""
"A new NEC2 input file may not be opened\n"
"while the Frequency Loop is running"
msgstr ""
```

from here:

```c
  if( !Nec2_Save_Warn(
        _("A new NEC2 input file may not be opened\n"
          "while the Frequency Loop is running")) )
    return;
```

**Questions:**

- Is it a problem that the first line of msgid is an empty string?
- Will it affect the ability for `dgettext` to find the translation when the lines are translated?
- Other considerations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is normal, this is how gettext works with multi-line strings, the first `""` line isn't an empty string it just says "this is a multi-line string". `xgettext` does this for lines that are too long (that can be controlled by `--no-wrap`) and for strings with [embedded new lines](https://www.gnu.org/software/gettext/manual/html_node/Normalizing.html).

The translation must be in the same format but other than that, there's no reason to worry.

Comment: And indeed string literal concatenation in `.po` files works the same way as in the C programming language.